# A question on motivic zeta-function

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives, conic-sections

It's well-known that over $\mathbb F_q$ every smooth projective conic $C$ is isomorphic to a projective line. So the formula for the motivic zeta-function $Z_{mot}(C)$ is evident since $S^n\mathbb P^1 \simeq \mathbb P^n$.

But what can one say when the finite field in the formulation of this question is replaced by an *arbitrary* field? Are there any references which can help me to determine the answer?

Answer (score 6):

$S^nC$ will equal $\mathbb P^n$ for $n$ even and a Severi-Brauer variety with the same Brauer class as $C$ for $n$ odd. In the $n$ odd case, its class in the Grothendieck group will be $[C] ( 1+ L^2 + \dots + L^{n-1})$.

Combining the even and odd cases, you get a formula for the motivic zeta function.

For details, and a much more general result, see Zeta Functions of Curves with No Rational Points by Daniel Litt.

Comment: Hi,
thank you very much! 
The desired result sounds quite elementary: isn't there an elementary proof of it? The Litt's proof doesn't seem to me to be so....

Comment: @JohnS. The difficulty in Litt's proof is mainly to do with working with Brauer-Severi varieties over a general base, rather than, as in your case, Brauer-Severi varieties over a point. One approach would be to extract the subset of the proof which is necessary in this case. For example, I think you need Theorem 24 (in the arXiv version, at least), but the proof of that isn't hard, and when you have that, you are almost done.